# document.querySelectorAll('') How does it works?

Tags: javascript

I would like some tips about JS querySelectorAll('').
I need to count some checkboxes to establish a maximun of selection. The problem is I dont want to count them all the checked, just the ones with the 'name=homeCheck' and in the way I'm using querySelectorAll it's not working fine:

```
function insertDeleteNews(data) {
if (checked == true && document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 6){
...}
}
```

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="homeCheck" id="homeCheck_<?=$row['id']."_".$row['id_azienda']?>" value="<?=$row['id']."_".$row['id_azienda']?>" <?= $rowHome ?"checked":""?> <?= !$rowNews ?"disabled":""?> onclick="insertDeleteNews(this.value)"></td>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question -- it appears you seem to know how `querySelectorAll` works already?

Comment: Where are you attempting to filter to `name=homeCheck`? You can combine CSS selectors - `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="homeCheck"]:checked')`, or if you are just looking for the ones matching the name `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="homeCheck"]')`.

Comment: thank you @JoshuaT ! I will try this, this was what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query for the name-property instead of the type-property:

```
input[name="name1"]:checked
```

**General example:**

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let count = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="name1"]:checked').length;
  console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="name1"> Name1 (1)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name2"> Name2 (1)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name1"> Name1 (2)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name2"> Name2 (2)<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="name1"> Name1 (3)<br>
<button id="button">Count Name1</button>
```

**Example - limit to max 3 checked:**

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="homeCheck"]');
for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('click', checkboxLimitTo3Checked);
}

function checkboxLimitTo3Checked(event) {
  let checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="homeCheck"]:checked').length;
  if (checked > 3) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="homeCheck"> homeCheck 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="homeCheck"> homeCheck 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="homeCheck"> homeCheck 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="homeCheck"> homeCheck 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="homeCheck"> homeCheck 5<br>
```

Comment: @SoniaMarianela i've added another example that is closer to the described behavior of your question. If that doesn't help you, then please explain what is exactly not working for you, so i could look into it.

Comment: yes @jan I used ('input[name="homeCheck"]:checked') and it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your function by

```
function insertDeleteNews(data) {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('input[name="homeCheck"]:checked').length > 6){
...}
}
```

This will find all the checked inputs with name = "homeCheck"

Comment: Thank u for your help! I tried this out but it didnt work, I will go with this exemple: document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="homeCheck"]:checked')